# JQuery - Round only one corner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to round one corner in JQuery. How would I do this? I tried:

```
   $(".under").corner("bottom-right 10px");
```

But that doesn't work. (Sorry if I'm asking noob questions, I just implemented JQuery today).

Comment: Have you considered using CSS to round your corners? Unless you specifically need rounded-corner-support for IE this may be a simpler and better solution.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, all IE versions lower than 9 don't support rounded CSS corners. I want to offer the highest availability to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a CSS-based IE-compatible solution, check out:

http://css3pie.com/

For JQuery-based solutions, check out:

http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/

http://www.curvycorners.net/

Answer (score 2):

Try using something like http://jsfiddle.net/2mnHM/. You will need to adjust it a bit as it is not cross browser. From what I understand you can get the same effect using different properties in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari and IE9; however IE8 and under is a whole different can of worms.

You will need to use a background image for IE, most likely. Or use a div positioned at the bottom left containing an `<img>` tag. You should be able to just use jQuery to detect if it is IE (a combination of `$.browser.IE` and `$.browser.version`).

Answer (score 1):

With jquery.corner.js (http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) you can do this:

```
jQuery('#flow').corner("TL 8px");     // top left
jQuery('#flow').corner("TR 15px");    // top right
jQuery('#flow').corner("BL 20px");    // bottom left
jQuery('#flow').corner("BR 2px");     // bottom right
jQuery('#flow').corner("top 30px");   // top left right
jQuery('#flow').corner("right 2px");  // top bottom right
jQuery('#flow').corner("bottom 2px"); // bottom left right
jQuery('#flow').corner("left 2px");   // top bottom left
```